# Create a list where each element is a pair of contiguous members from given vector

Tags: r, split

Or how to split a vector into pairs of contiguous members and combine them in a list?

Supose you are given the vector

```
map <-seq(from = 1, to = 20, by = 4)
```

which is

```
1  5  9  13  17
```

My goal is to create the following list

```
path <- list(c(1,5), c(5,9), c(9,13), c(13,17))
```

This is supposed to represent the several path segments that the map is sugesting us to follow. In order to go from 1 to 17, we must first take the first path (`path[1]`), then the second path (`path[2]`), and all the way to the end.

My first attempt lead me to:

```
path <- split(aux <- data.frame(S = map[-length(map)], E = map[-1]), row(aux))
```

But I think it would be possible without creating this auxiliar data frame
and avoiding the performance decrease when the initial vector (the `map`) is to big. Also, it returns a warning message which is quite alright, but I like to avoid them.

Then I found this here on stackoverflow (not exactly like this, this is the adapted version for my problem):

```
mod_map <- c(map, map[c(-1,-length(map))])
mod_map <- sort(mod_map)
split(mod_map, ceiling(seq_along(mod_map)/2))
```

which is a simpler solution, but I have to use this modified version of my `map`.

Pherhaps I'm asking too much as I already got two solutions. But, could it be possible to have a third one, so that I don't have so use data frames as in my first solution and can use the original map, unlike my second solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `Map` on the vector ('map' - better not to use function names - it is a function from `purrr`) with 1st and last element removed and concatenate elementwise

```
Map(c, map[-length(map)], map[-1])
```

---

Or as @Sotos mentioned, `split` can be used which would be faster

```
split(cbind(map[-length(map)], map[-1]), seq(length(map)-1))
```

Comment: Or you can avoid `Map` by `split(cbind(map[-length(map)], map[-1]), seq(length(map)-1))`